# Joining two pandas dataframes by latest date

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes (`d`, containing `date1`,`name`) and another (`d1`, containing `date2`,`name`,`rank`). I need to join these two on `name` such that for each row in first dataframe I assign the latest rank as of `date1`.

**i.e. `d1.name = d2.name` and `d2.date2` is latest `d1.date1`**

What is the easiest way of doing this?

```
import pandas as pd

d = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['20070105', '20130105', '20150102', 
'20170106', '20190106'], 'name': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']})

d

       date name
0  20070105    a
1  20130105    b
2  20150102    a
3  20170106    b
4  20190106    a


d1 = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['20140105', '20160105', '20180103', 
 '20190106'], 'rank' : [1, 2, 1,5], 'name': ['a', 'b', 'a', '
 ...: b']})

d1

   date name  rank
 0  20140105    a     1
 1  20160105    b     2
 2  20180103    a     2
 3  20190106    b     1
```

I'm expecting 'rank' to be added to 'd' and have output like this:

```
       date name  Rank
0  20070105    a  NaN
1  20130105    b  NaN
2  20150102    a  1
3  20170106    b  2
4. 20190106    a  2
```

Comment: Done. Added code example

Answer (score 1):

I assume you required this.

sort your `second dataframe` in `ascending` order with date, then `drop_duplicate`s with `keep='last'`, Now apply `pd.merge` with first dataframe with processed second dataframe.

```
df2=df2.sort_values(on='date')
temp=df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['name'], keep='last')
print (pd.merge(df1,temp, on=['name'], how='left'))
```

Note: As you failed to post sample input and output, I assumes column name and variable like the above. For exact result provide sample input and output.

Comment: Added code sample now. The above solution may not work.